# Trying to copy what friendly_id does to turn a strong into a slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, friendly-id

I need to copy the way friendly_id changes text into slugs.

I was using this for my app

```
text        = "random text"
text_gsubed = (value.gsub ' ', '-')
slug        = text_gsubed.downcase
```

But recently I realised for text with non alphabetic or numeric characters it generates a different slug to what firendly_id generates e.g.

```
text        = "random >> text"
text_gsubed = (value.gsub ' ', '-')
slug        = text_gsubed.downcase
```

The slug the code above generates = `random->>-text`

The slug feindly_id generates = `random-text`

I though maybe they have a built in method you can use globally like `text.slug` or `text.friendly_id` if you have the gem installed but I cant see one. I also looked into their files to find the method that turns the string into a slug but cant find it.

How can I mimic what friendly_id is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably look into the ActiveSupport::Inflections#parameterize.

In your case you should be able to call:

```
text.parameterize
```

If you want to combine with other parameters also, maybe id or something you could do:

```
[id, title, others].join(' ').parameterize
```